# NHibernate Configuration - move to web.config file

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, configuration-files

I am having trouble setting up NHibernate configuration. I can get it to work if I create a seperate configuration file, then when I call Configuration.configure I point to the absolute path ("C:\My Documents... etc...) of the configuration file. this will obviously be a problem when I try to move from development to production. So I thought I would move the configuration to the web.config file, but it fails. So, in the web.config file I have:

```
<configSections>
<section name="hibernate-configuration"
  type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
</configSections>

<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
<session-factory>
  <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
  <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=MyServerName;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True</property>
  <property name="connection.isolation">ReadCommitted</property>
  <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>
  <property name="current_session_context_class">web</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Then I am testing like this:

```
<TestFixture()> _
Public Class GenerateSchema_Fixture

    <Test()> _
    Public Sub Can_generate_schema()

        Dim cfg = New NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration()
        cfg.Configure() 
        cfg.AddAssembly(GetType(Question).Assembly)
        Dim exp As NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport = New NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport(cfg)
        exp.Execute(False, True, False)

    End Sub


End Class
```

And when I run this test I get:

```
------ Test started: Assembly: ECEHire.Test.dll ------

Test 'ECEHire.Test.Tests.GenerateSchema_Fixture.Can_generate_schema' failed: NHibernate.HibernateException : Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 49.
```

----> System.ArgumentException : Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 49.
    at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.Execute(Action`1 scriptAction, Boolean export, Boolean justDrop)
    at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.Execute(Boolean script, Boolean export, Boolean justDrop)
    GenerateSchema_Fixture.vb(19,0): at ECEHire.Test.Tests.GenerateSchema_Fixture.Can_generate_schema()
    --ArgumentException
    at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
    at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
    at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(String connectionString, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(String value)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
    at NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection()
     at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.Execute(Action`1 scriptAction, Boolean export, Boolean justDrop)

```
0 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, took 3.30 seconds (NUnit 2.5.10).
```

I am thinking in the direction of: The web.config file is in my main project and not the test project. Does that mean I have to use a seperate config file for NHibernate. If so, I still have the same problem (I still get the same error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should have a different configuration file for each environment: testing and web. In the testing configuration current_session_context_class should not be web (instead try with ThreadStaticSessionContext).